# running pylint and pycodestyle in jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pylint

I have a git repository with some python files in it. I want to check these files under pylint and pycodestyle standards for python in a jenkins pipeline. The node I want to run is a windows environment. I have written the following code.

```
   stage('Check file for pylint'){
            powershell"""
            .\\venv\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1
            ${WORKSPACE}\\code_analyzer\\check_pylint.bat | tee pylint.log
            """
            pylint = scanForIssues blameDisabled: true, tool: pyLint(pattern: 'pylint.log')

        }
        stage('Check files for pycodestyle'){
        powershell"""
        .\\venv\\Scripts\\Activate.ps1
        ${WORKSPACE}\\code_analyzer\\check_pycodestyle.bat 2>&1 | tee pycodestyle.log
        """
        pycodestyle = scanForIssues blameDisabled: true, tool: pep8(pattern: 'pycodestyle.log')
        }
    }
```

is this correct and sufficient or do I need to add another stage in the file such as analysis?

Comment: What's the result of the script ? Surely you could tell if it's sufficient yourself by seeing if it raises the same warning then locally and fail as it should when adding an error ?

Comment: There is an analysis stage after this (Not shown above). Which will analyze all the warning from pylint and pycodestyle. The whole point of doing this, we can use jenkins CI tool to continuously monitor this step and we do not need to do it ourselves everytime we write or edit a script.